# Mission five of MSD, any hint how to handle it?

Tags: metal-slugs-defense

The last update added to the game "Mission", which are staged with preseted deck and no base upgrade. The first 4 ones are quite easy, but I m struggling at the 5th one.

This mission give you Tarma, Fat Tarma, Drill Slug and Sand Bag, with the goal to stay alive 80seconds.

Problem is, the map start with 5 wall of worms, which are suicidary charging powerful unit if activated by one of your unit going near them. Basically, if activated, it s game over since your unit can t spawn and kill them fast enought.

Add to that a powerful giant worm which can kill in one shot both Tarma, and it seems to me that you re supposed to spam Drill Slug, that have a too long recharge time.

Can anybody hint me on the strategy to use?

(The only thing I found on internet is to use Sand Bag and Drill Slug at the first wave to try to kill the more maggot possible, but past this point, I usually have maggot + giant worm breaching the sand bag, kill Drill Slug and my base before being able to respawn Drill Slug, both Tarma get killed before being able to use the shotgun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the drill slug as the first unit as it can plow through all grubs (save drill slug special move for giant worm) and follow by tarma to shot gun them. do not use Sand Bag first or you will be over run by the grubs.

Just my opinion as this is how I clear the area.

Comment: In fact, I did used the Drill Slug's Special againts the maggot, before it overrun me, but I had the time to get Tarma just behind to shotgun the Giant Worm. Althought, I killed the Giant Worm just before game over, so it may be luck.